# How can I restore an activity already open?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-api-3

I have two activity A and B. The activity A starts activity B. In activity B I have a map with a marker. This activity B will start a service that returns every x seconds the new positions of the markers on the map, tracing the route marker. I wish that when I press the back button to return to the activity A, when I return to activity B, I want to display the map as well as I had left it. 
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method onbackpressed and write a function inside this method which return you the geolocation of marker when back was pressed .persist this location in your app in whichever way you prefer .static or constants or sharedpref or even pass to activity a .
When activity b is launched again check if this variable has a value and if it does then send this location to market and map

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following row in your manifest to activity B:

```
...

android:launchMode="singleTask"

...
```

For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

This is exactly what you need. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Save your positions on Sharepref or Sqlite ondestroy(), and when Activity B is active again and your data (on local storage) is not null then read from there and start again the route tracing for new positions